# React native Android with API level 28

Tags: react-native

I created a new react native application using create-react-native-app.
Everything goes well and I want to upload my apk. Play console prompts with an error mentioning minimum API level is 28.
My current configuration is:

buildToolsVersion 28.0.3
minSdkVersion 21
compileSdkVersion 28
supportLibVersion 28.0.0
targetSdkVersion 27

When I change the targetSdkVersion to 28 and execute react-native run-android, the app loads in my phone but the metro bundler doesn't load the app.
It displays

```
Loading dependency graph... Done
```

And that's it. When I change back targetSdkVersion to 27, then the app loads and the bundler also loads the app and everything back to work.

I search but found things related to old react-native versions.

Any suggestions how to set up react-native app for API level 28?